# Populating Dynamic Fields in groovy GSP by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

Hey Guys i am trying to populate dynamic fields in groovy GSP by using javascript and Groovy markup

***Here's the Effort 1 ->Works fine using plain html ***

```
<r:script>
  function createField()
  {
    var variable=0; 
    var d="<input type='text' name='item["+variable+"]' id='item["+variable+"]'/>";
    reutrn d;
  } 
</r:script>
```

***Here's the Effort 2 ->JavaScript Error while using Groovy tags  ***

```
<r:script>
  function createField()
  {
    var variable = 0; 
    var d = "<g:textField name='item["+variable+"]' id='item["+variable+"]' />";
    return d;
  }
</r:script>
```

By Using above function browser ends up with the error :**javascript uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token illegal**
So i decided to encode the tag using Grails InLine codec **encodeAs="JavaScript"**.

***Here's the Effort 3 ->Error using Groovy tags  ***

```
y<r:script>
   function createField()
   {
      var variable=0; 
      var d="<g:textField name='item["+variable+"]' id='item["+variable+"]' encodeAs="JavaScript"/>";
      return d;
   }
</r:script>
```

Problem with the third effort while encoding the tags, quotes besides the variable are also encoded so the output is something like u003b+variable+\u0026#39, this makes the nonidentical form fields which are unable to process further.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You've misspelled return statement.

Comment: imho, you should go with `Effort 1`. i don't think you gain much by using `g:textField`

Comment: thanks for the response aldrin but sometime theres is a situation where one have to implement groovy tags i;e 
<g:select from="${classname.list()}" value="${classname.attrib}"/>
i am unable to find the alternate solution, please suggest if you have one

Answer (score 0):

GSP and javascript are evaluated at different times which is causing this not to work. GSP is executed server side then the result is sent back to the client the JS is executed client side. If you view source of the page from your browser you will see that the createField function has the g:textField already replaced.

Comment: thanks for the response jeff, i know that groovy markup is replaced by plain html tags but in the present scenario i am dealing with <g:select> tag which have built in attribute "from", which take class instance list as a value to populate the options i;e <option>1</option>

Comment: Yes but you can use the GSP tags to generate what will be consumed by the JS but what you had in your question would cause that whole g tag to be replaced. Thus the +variable+ would go away before it ever tried to assign anything to var d.